# Fluid simulation particles are offset from the effectors

Tags: fluid-simulation, collision, mantaflow

[image]

Every time I simulate a fluid simulation in blender it always 'hovers' above the desired collision. I've tried applying the scale, I've also tried to set the normals to a smaller size but still no changes. I'm not sure what could be causing this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6IJE.jpg

[image]

Comment: if u provide blend file, i can help you

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=gLk8r7mx" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/gLk8r7mx/)

Answer (score 1):

This little box which you can see in your domain represents the "smallest unit" of your fluid. If it is too big, it cannot "see"/recognize your obstacle. So you could either increase your domain resolution and/or increase the thickness of your obstacle.

[image]

to make it work change this:

select your plane (obstacle), add a solidify modifier like this:

[image]

Note: It has to be before your fluid modifier.

Uncheck your "is planar"

[image]

bake again and you will get:

[image]

or...without the modifier:

uncheck "is planar" and change resolution to 120:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Please click on the checkmark left of my answer, if it helped you. Thank you!